# How do I evaluate the accumulated error of a repeated Poisson process?

Tags: repeated-measures, poisson-process

I'm quite newbie in stats, so sorry if I write anything stupid. I'm dealing with a statistical process in my master in electronics and I'm kind of stuck. Consider a device that counts individual photons impinging on it.

The number of impinging photons is given by a Poisson distribution:
$$P {\left( n _{i }\right) }=\frac{{H }^{i }\cdot {e }^{-H }}{i !}$$

The photon count is converted by the device and results in a voltage at the output. Since the device has an inherent voltage noise, this output is normally distributed around a mean, which is equal to the actual number of photons times a Conversion Gain ($CG$). So, for  a number $n_i$ of photons:
$$ p {\left( u _{out }|n _{i }\right) }\approx N {\left( i \cdot CG ,{\sigma _{u_{out} }}^{2 }\right) }=\frac{1 }{\sqrt{2 \cdot {\sigma }^{2 }\pi }}{e }^{-{\left( \frac{{{\left( u -i \cdot CG \right) }}^{2 }}{2 \cdot {\sigma_{u_{out}} }^{2 }}\right) }} $$

Now, going towards classifying photon counts as a function of the measured voltage, the conditional probability that a measured voltage $u_{out}$ was generated by a number $n_i$ of photons is:

$$P {\left( n _{i }|u _{out }\right) }=\frac{\frac{1 }{\sqrt{2 \cdot \pi {\sigma_{u_{out}} }^{2 }}}{e }^{{\left( -\frac{{{\left( u _{out }-i \cdot CG \right) }}^{2 }}{2 \cdot {\sigma_{u_{out}} }^{2 }}\right) }}\cdot \frac{{H }^{i }\cdot {e }^{-H }}{i !}}{\sum _{j =0 }^{FWC }\frac{1 }{\sqrt{2 \cdot \pi {\sigma_{u_{out}} }^{2 }}}{e }^{{\left( -\frac{{{\left( u _{out }-j \cdot CG \right) }}^{2 }}{2 \cdot {\sigma_{u_{out}} }^{2 }}\right) }}\cdot \frac{{H }^{j }\cdot {e }^{-H }}{j !}\; }\\ = \frac{{e }^{\frac{{\left( +2 u _{out }\cdot i \cdot CG -{i }^{2 }\cdot {CG }^{2 }\right) }}{2 \cdot {\sigma_{u_{out}} }^{2 }}}\cdot \frac{{H }^{i }}{i !}}{\sum _{j =0 }^{FWC }{e }^{\frac{{\left( +2 u _{out }\cdot j \cdot CG -{j }^{2 }\cdot {CG }^{2 }\right) }}{2 \cdot {\sigma_{u_{out}} }^{2 }}}\cdot \frac{{H }^{j }}{j !}\; }$$

I will then classify the measured voltage as $i$ photons whenever $P(n_i\mid u_{out}) > P(n_j\mid u_{out}) \quad for \quad all \quad j\neq i$.

Now, suppose I am using this device to estimate the time that light pulses from a source take to hit this device. I do this by taking a cycle period of $T_0$ and dividing it in many bins of time $\Delta t$. Then the number of photons that impinges on the device during each bin is stored, and another cycle starts, and the counts of the corresponding bins are summed. After a given number of cycles, the integrated photon counts are plotted in a histogram, resulting in a distribution that is usually approximated by a Gaussian (disregard the fact that it is not the image below). Then I use some algorithm to find the highest peak, which is proportional to the value I want to estimate.

[image: Histogram of the photon counts accumulated over a certain number of cycles]

The approximated Gaussian will have the form:
$$\frac{S_R}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_\tau^2}}\cdot e^{-\frac{(\tau - \tau_{TOF})^2}{2\sigma_\tau^2}}$$

Now, finally, the question: assuming that I have a high voltage noise value ($\sigma_{u_{out}}$) in the first part of my explanation, which causes an error in distinguishing the number the photons that actually impinged in the device in one of the bins - how does that affect the error on the time pdf, as a function of the number of integration cycles?

I'm not sure if what I wrote is clear, but I can't see exactly how to relate these two things. I've found some stuff on how to sum two independent Poisson processes, but in this case I repeat and accumulate the same process...? Since I have an error from the first process, and I will repeat this process many times, is the total error in accumulated photon count a scalar times the error ($N_{cycles}\cdot \frac{\sigma_{u_{out}}}{CG}$)? If I integrate too few cycles, can the error in one of the bins be so great that it becomes higher than the peak that corresponds to the mean time? With what probability? How do I determine the minimum integration time to prevent that, or at least to have a maximum acceptable probability that that happens?

Anyway, if you can just point me out towards what I should read to understand this, it would be great. Thanks in advance.